# How to apply internationalization for Bootstrap Tags Input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, bootstrap-tags-input

I'm working with internationalization(jQuery i18n) for my project, And I've used Bootstrap Tags Input. I want to apply Localization for "Display Text" of The Tag.

Note: I've used **"Objects as tags"** in Bootstrap Tags Input. for more Ref: [Bootstrap Tags Input](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its quite simple, In Bootstrap Tags Input `itemText` is available for displaying text of Tag. So we can do Localization when it returns an Item.

We can Change in `bootstrap-tagsinput.js` at line Number 12.

Change `return this.itemValue(item);` to
`return changeText('Label_'+this.itemValue(item),this.itemValue(item));`

```
changeText(key,Actual Text);
```

The `changeText` is a function which returns Localization Text for that "Key", if Localization Text is not available then it returns "Actual Text" that we are displaying.

Comment: Thanks Mahendra, It works Fine but can't we do without make any Changes in JS file level??